# Remove certain labels from homepage in blogger

Tags: xhtml, hide, blogger, label, posts

How can I hide posts with specific labels on homepage in blogger? I've tried using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060776/how-to-hide-blogger-posts-with-specific-label . But it partially works if you use the single label code (it still shows the data of the posts that are hidden), and it doesnt work at all if I use the multiple labels code. Any solutions?

```
  <!-- hide specific labels -->
  <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
      <b:if cond='data:label.name != &quot;about-me&quot;'>
        <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
      </b:if>
    </b:loop>
  <b:else/>
    <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
  </b:if>
  <!-- end hide specific labels -->
```

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about that topic, maybe this solution helps: http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/2014/07/blogger-take-certain-post-out-of-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

label is used to put post in same location
if you made a label love and all you made
 post in blogger with love label will open with 
when you click on label name . so many new 
blogger want to remove that so if you want
to [remove](http://5gblogger.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-delete-label-from-blogger-post.html) label from blogger.